# Prevent multiple instantiation of an activity

Tags: android

Is it possible to make an activity singleton?
I have found many resources that just tell to use `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` or `singleTask`, but I would constructor to be called only once.

Ideally, I would like to be able to specify custom constructor/builder method e.g. `getInstance()`

Comment: That's not how activity works. The resources you found are correct.

Comment: Ok. If that is not possible, is there a way to achieve something similar?

Comment: While it is technically possible to make any class a singleton, an activity is one of the worst candidates due to its lifecycle. You will not avoid the lifecycle handling, sorry. Why do you need this?

Comment: Too bad, but thank you for your answers.
I am making a single activity application and was planning on handling this stuff elsewhere. But I guess I will have to stick it into the activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store your references in `Application` instead of an `Activity`. The application class is de facto a singleton. You only need to define your access methods.

```
public class BaseApplication extends Application {

  private static BaseApplication sInstance = null;

  public synchronized static BaseApplication getInstance() {
    return sInstance;
  }

  public synchronized static void setInstance(BaseApplication app) {
    sInstance = app;
  }

  public BaseApplication() {
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setInstance(this);
}
```

Now you can access it by calling `BaseApplication.getInstance()`. As a bonus the `Application` extends `Context` so now you have an application context reference anywhere you want (safe to use pretty much everywhere except inflating layouts).

Don't forget to define this class as the base application class in your manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="com.yourapp.BaseApplication">
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually they do as follows:

1) define what comprise the `Activity` state

2) Save the state in `onSaveInstanceState`

3) Restore the state in `onCreate` or in `onRestoreInstanceState`